# Issue with Visual Studio 2013, MVC 4.0 application and Web API 2.2 Nuget Package Install

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, nuget, asp.net-web-api2

I have a standard MVC 4.0 project for my application which was working correctly. I needed to use WebAPI within the same project so I installed the Nuget Package for WebAPI 2.2.

All seemed well and WebAPI ran fine after some tests, and my project also ran fine, except for the fact that now I cannot add standard MVC controllers, they all refer to adding a WebAPI controller and also options to add a standard view from an action inside a standard MVC controller using the Right Click context menu are now missing.

It seems as if it is assuming it is a WebAPI  project only now, however I still need all MVC related options to be present. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Any advice on this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to use both WebAPI and MVC in the same project.

I managed to get it pretty much working using two projects in the same solution e.g. MyProject.MVC project and MyProject.API. However this turned out to be a bit clumsy, the biggest issue for me was getting Unity to work for both cases. Eventually I got that working too, but after a few days I figured I didn't actually need the WebAPI portion and it was causing more work than it was worth, so I removed that from the solution.

Not sure this answers your question tbh, but hopefully useful in some way. Btw in the next version of MVC6 ([vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview)) they are apparently planning to combine the Mvc and WebApi parts into a single framework, so this should ease the pain!